# JPA query fails on empty list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have this entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id Long id;
    @ManyToMany List<Foo> foos;
    @ManyToMany List<Bar> bars;
}
```

I need to prevent overlapping, so if any `foos` contains a `foo` with `id 1` and a `bar` with `id 2` there cannot be another MyEntity containing the same combination of foos and bars.

So i made this repository:

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>  {
    List<MyEntity> findAllByFoosInAndBarsIn(List<MyEntity> foo, List<MyEntity> bar);
}
```

This works fine as long as both lists contains something. But if for some reason either is empty, the result set is too.

Comment: Did you try passing `null` instead? Or is it rather a `...FoosInOrBarsIn`? That `And` would basically mean `foos in {...} and bars in {...}` and since `x in {}` never can be true no entity would match if _either_ parameter list would be true.

Comment: Check the generated SQL statement

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is not the default one. So you need to provide your required logic to a custom query. The following should do the job using named parameters.

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>  {
    
   @Query("select m from MyEntity m WHERE 
     ( (NOT(:foo IS EMPTY) AND m.foos IN :foo) OR :foo IS EMPTY ) AND
     ( (NOT(:bar IS EMPTY) AND m.bars IN :bar) OR :bar IS EMPTY ) 
     List<MyEntity> findAllByFoosInAndBarsIn(@Param("foo") List<MyEntity> foo, 
                                             @Param("bar") List<MyEntity> bar);
}
```

In the provided query the filtering IN (...) for a provided list, would apply only if the provided list is not empty. If it is empty the filter IN (...) will not be applied in the where clause.

Comment: Thank you for this, i will give it a try!

Comment: This gave me a `org.hibernate.QueryException: expecting '=', found '('`.

Comment: @jared I have updated the query try with this one